# Calling ViewPager inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager2

I am designing an Onboarding screen with the help of ViewPager. The ViewPager sits inside a fragment underlying my MainActivity class. The error arises when I pass the ViewPager adapter class to the ViewPager inside my fragment! It throws NullPointerException and after breakpoint debugging I find that the inflater inside my PagerAdapter class is null.
I have tried some alternatives to get the inflater working but no luck! I ll post my codes below:

ViewPager Fragment class:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager viewpager;
LinearLayout dotsLayout;
SliderAdapter sliderAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);

    viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerFragment);
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.dotsLayout);

    sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(view.getContext());
   
    viewpager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter); //The error is thrown here
    

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}}
```

ViewPager Adapter Class:

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context1;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public int[] slide_images = {
        R.drawable.band,
        R.drawable.studio,
        R.drawable.videoshoot
};
public String[] slide_headings = {
        "REHEARSAL PAD", "RECORDING STUDIO", "SESSION VIDEOSHOOT"
};
public String[] slide_desc ={
        String.valueOf(R.string.rehearsal_desc),
        String.valueOf(R.string.studio_desc),
        String.valueOf(R.string.videoshoot_desc)
};

public  SliderAdapter(Context context){

    context1 = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slide_headings.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
    return view== (ConstraintLayout)object;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

    //ViewPager Sliding Images and Desc
      inflater = (LayoutInflater)context1.getSystemService(context1.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context1);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_layout,container,false);

    ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.SliderImageView);
    TextView slideHeading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SliderTextView1);
    TextView slideDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SliderTextView2);

    slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
    slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
    slideDesc.setText(slide_desc[position]);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

    container.removeView((ConstraintLayout)object);
}}
```

And the Exception Logs are given below:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.soundflixstudios, PID: 13363
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.soundflixstudios.onboarding.ViewPagerFragment.onCreateView(ViewPagerFragment.java:43)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7099)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)

Any help is appreciated, and yes I have gone through multiple post in stackoverflow but didnt find any solutionhence reaching out with a new question!
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have added the xml for "view_pager_fragment" layout

```
enter code here<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".onboarding.ViewPagerFragment">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/sliderViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="66dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show `fragment_view_pager.xml` file?

Comment: @SonTruong i have added the xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause**

In `view_pager_fragment.xml` file, you declare a `ViewPager2` with id `sliderViewPager` but in `ViewPagerFragment` class, you use a `ViewPager` variable and assign a view with id `viewPagerFragment` to it.

**Solution**

**Step 1.** Change `fragment_view_pager.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/sliderViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dotsLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2.** In `ViewPagerFragment` class, change your code from

```
viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerFragment);
```

to

```
viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.sliderViewPager);
```

Comment: Wow how did I make such a blunt error! Thank you so much @son! I was about to scrap the entire flow of fragments but you saved me! :D thanks

Comment: @CodexRat Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your xml file ( viewPagerFragment). In normal case, nullPointerException will show up when you missing references to your xml, or missing create xml tag( different screen- landscape/portrait)

Comment: Yes I have added the xml file

Comment: as i saw you using tag xml <ViewPager2> with id sliderViewPager. Not viewpagerFragement as you code in 

'viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerFragment);'

change that id, and you can fix your problem

Comment: Thanks @TheZero! It finally worked! I really made a stupid mistake. Much love!

Comment: Lol. Thats fine.